# Metal Slug 3 won't work on MacMame

Tags: mame, metal-slug-3

I have recently downloaded the game emulator MacMame to play Metal Slug 3. I got MacMame to work, but when I downloaded the Metal Slug rom, it will show up in the game directory, but when I click on it to play, it says files are missing.

I did some research and found that you also needed a Neo Geo BIOS to play, so I downloaded the file and put it in. I tried to play Metal Slug again but it did not work - I got the same error, that files are missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, you're supposed to dump your own Neo Geo's BIOS, because if you don't, it's considered piracy. But to be honest, there aren't many people with the knowledge or tools to dump a device's BIOS onto a PC, so I'll just leave it at a comment. Good luck with finding an answer. Not sure if you'll need it, though.

Comment: So what have the people done that say they play metal slug on their laptop?

Comment: They knew sites that provided them with valid BIOS files and roms. There are tons of emulator sites around the web, some are pretty much garbage, some are golden. Try different BIOS files (from Neo Geo) and roms - not every rom works with every BIOS (dependencies can be different).

Comment: Ok, so just keep trying until something works. Thanks.

Comment: It's still piracy unless you own the game itself as well.